# Align in equation

Tags: math-mode, alignment

can someone help me to put my vdots exactly under the middle of e.g.   `t_{1}(\boldsymbol{x})` and second vdots under the middle of  `h\left(\hat{g}_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})\right)`.

```
 h\left(\hat{g}_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})\right)
  \begin{equation*}
    \boldsymbol{t}(\boldsymbol{x})=\left\{ \begin{aligned}
    t_{1}(\boldsymbol{x})& = h\left(\hat{g}_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})\right) \\
    \vdots&  \vdots \\
    t_{n}(\boldsymbol{x})&  = h\left(\hat{g}_{n}(\boldsymbol{x})\right) 
    \end{aligned} \right
    \end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you just need an `array`. I've removed some `\left`/`\right` which were making no good but rather damage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{t}(\boldsymbol{x})
=\left\{
\begin{array}{c@{\;}c@{\;}c} % or \begin{array}{@{}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{}} if you prefer less spacing
    t_{1}(\boldsymbol{x})&=& h(\hat{g}_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})) \\  %  <--- shouldn't this be \hat{g}_{1} ?
    \vdots&&\vdots\\
    t_{n}(\boldsymbol{x})&=& h(\hat{g}_{n}(\boldsymbol{x})) 
    \end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly `\halign` TeX primitive. The `\vdots` are centered because we have `\hfil$#$\hfil` in the `\halign` preamble.

```
\def\x{{\bf x}}
$$
  {\bf t}(\x) = \left\{
     \vcenter{\halign{\hfil$#$\hfil&${}#{}$&\hfil$#$\hfil\cr
         t_1(\x) & = & h(\hat g_i(\x)) \cr
         \vdots &   & \vdots \cr
         t_n(\x) & = & h(\hat g_n(\x)) \cr
     }}
  \right\}
$$
```